# DWR Upload Multiple Files

Tags: java, javascript, file-upload, dwr

I have a DWR implementation for uploading a file to a server, (FTP in this case) but I would like to know how to send multiple file using DWR.

This is what I have for single file:

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="uploadFile();"/>
<input type="text" id="fileName" />
```

JavaScript

```
    function uploadFile() {
            if($('#file').val()!='' && $('#fileName').val() != ''){
                var file = dwr.util.getValue('file');
                FTPService.uploadFile(file, 'Alfresco/Sites/Licencias de Alcoholes', $('#fileName').val(), function(uploaded){
                    if(uploaded == "Success"){
                        alert("Se subió el archivo al FTP de Alfresco");
                    }else{
                        alert("Ha ocurrido el siguiente error al subir el archivo: \n"
                                + uploaded);    
                    }
                });
            }else{
                alert("Debes seleccionar un archivo antes de tratar de subirlo");
            }
        }
```

Java Service:

```
public String uploadFile(InputStream file, String remoteFolder, String remoteFileName) throws IOException{

    FTPConnectionFactory ftpConnectionFactory = new FTPConnectionFactory();

    //Obtenemos la conexión al servidor FTP
    FTPClient ftpClient = ftpConnectionFactory.getConnection("1.1.1.1", 21, "user", "pass");

    Document document = new Document();

    //Seteamos las propiedades del documento a subir
    document.setFile(file);
    document.setRemoteFolder(remoteFolder);
    document.setRemoteFileName(remoteFileName);

    //Se sube el documento y se devuelve el resultado
    return UploadDocument.upload(ftpClient, document);

}
```

This works fine for 1 file but I want to upload multiple files using the "multiple" attribute of the html input file.

I hope you guys can give me a hint.

Best Regards,
Roberto

Comment: I see `if($('#file').val()!='' && $('#fileName').val() != ''){` you are hard coding the file to get you should pass that in to your function

Comment: Well I can give you the way how to do it! You just need to make as much inputs as you want and put those in an array in Java . then you can do the for loop on Java code which uploads the file....

Comment: Hello Moises, yes in that case the name of the input its file, and it is just and example, but what I want to do is to use the html input file with the "multiple" propertie. And send the multiple selected files to the server.
On server side, right now I'm recieving an InputStream, but I don't know if that can work for multiple files, and if so, how.
Gauravjot, I don't want to use multiple inputs, but just one with the option multiple.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the client library that you are using to do the upload.
It seems that you are using FTP. Could you give more details on which library it is.

If you are not forced to use FTP, you can do a simple HTTP post to the alfresco webscript.

Besides, you can always execute the javascript code for the upload once for every file to upload (this is actually how the alfresco uploader works).

Comment: Hello Marco, I'm using the apache ftpClient from common-net.
The thing here is not how to upload multiple files to alfresco which I can do with the code I have doing a loop, but the question is more how to read the multiple files that the input can send.
As you can see I receive an InputStream, but, that is for one file, but what happens if I put the option multiple in the html input file control, how can I receive them on server side, can I receive the with the input stream? if yes, how to convert them to multiple files before I send them.